How to get the current date in Odoo 17 Automation Rules: Execute Code
We are trying to get the current date in the automation rules in Odoo 17 using code. In the comments section it's mentioned that we can use python datetime libraries, however it seems that today() or now() functions are not accessbile.
May you suggest a way.
datetime.today()
datetime.now()


datetime.datetime.today().date()


Try:
today_date = datetime.datetime.now()

